# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null, when trying to change BG color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Note: I'm currently learning JS and am trying to build a flowchart creator app.

[image]

Each element (rectangle, circle, oval) has an edit button with a class '.edit', only visible when hovered over the element (see pencil icon). Each element has a unique Id.

[image]

When the pencil button with '.edit' class is clicked, it pulls up a side menu bar where the element's background color can be changed using the Pickr library. Below is how I am listening for clicks and changing an element's background color.

```
 $("document").ready(() => {
        $(".edit").click(function() {
            let id = this.id;
            document.getElementById("right-bar").style.width = "240px";
            document.getElementById("top-bar-right").style.width = "240px";
            document.getElementById("canvas").style.right = "17%";

            changeBGcolor("element" + id);
        })
    });

function changeBGcolor(something) {

const backgroundPickr = Pickr.create({
    el: '.bg-color-picker',
    theme: 'classic',
    default: $("#" + something).css("background-color"),

    swatches: [
        'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
        'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
        'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
        'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
        'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
        'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
        'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
    ],

    components: {

        preview: true,

        interaction: {
            hex: true,
            rgba: true,
            input: true,
            save: true
        }
    }
});

backgroundPickr.on('save', (color) => {

    $(`#${something}`).css("background-color", color.toHEXA().toString());
    //colorBG = color.toHEXA().toString();
})
```

};

```
<!-- Here is the HTML bit --> 
 <div id="right-bar">
    <div class="list-group customizations">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action custom-options">
            Element Background Color 
            <div class="bg-picker bg-color-change">
                <div class="bg-color-picker"></div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When I click on the pencil button ('.edit') for the first time, the right bar pulls up and I can change the element's background color just fine. However, the issue I'm facing right now is regardless of which element's pencil icon I click after the initial color change, any new selected color is only applied to the initial element (the one whose pencil button I first clicked and made the color change to). Below is a screenshot of the errors that arise when I click on the pencil button of other elements after making the initial color change.

[image]

P.S. I apologize for not summarizing my issue better. English is not my native language and this is only the second question I have asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since you are crashing inside the color picker library, I'd try and trace back the source of that `null` to your code, using the debugger, based on the state of things when you break due to the exception.

Comment: In order to help you with this it would be really important to get a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see it in fail "live" and poke around if needed.

Comment: Oh and please include the error (incl. stack) as **text** as well, not only as image. [It's a reason to get downvotes.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: You say `Each element (rectangle, circle, oval) has an edit button with a class '.edit'`. Could you please post this code as well?